# Htaccess replace %20 with hyphen + redirect to new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)$ news?title=$1
RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)$ carbrands?brand=$1
```

The problem is that some car brands contain two words, so it gives the following result:

```
example.com/cars/alfa%20romeo
```

How can I change my code so that people get redirected to:

```
example.com/cars/alfa-romeo
```

I would probably have to add [R=301,L] to redirect to the new url, but how to tell that the correct url should contain a hyphen instead of the "%20" ?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^cars/(\S+)\s+(\S+)$ cars/$1-$2 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following code right below `RewriteEngine On` works to replace all spaces by a hyphen.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

Comment: `%{THE_REQUEST}` always contain spaces. And this `[^\s%20]+` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add this right below "RewriteEngine On"

```
RewriteRule ^cars/(.*)(?:\ )(.*)$ /cars/$1-$2 [L,E=DASH:Y]
RewriteCond %{ENV:DASH} Y
RewriteRule ^([^\ ]+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I added your code right below `RewriteEngine On` but it still doesn't find `example.com/cars/alfa-romeo`.

It doesn't even find `example.com/cars/alfa%20romeo` anymore...

Comment: I found the answer. Thanks anyway!